# Algolia search result order

Tags: search, algolia

We have an Algolia attribute field called *tags* where we have entered relevant terms for the items people want to search.

Record #1 has tags:

> {"iphone", "phone"}

Record #2 has tags:

> {"phone", "wifi"}

If someone searches for *phone*, how can we make sure Record #1 is returned above Record #2? We want Algolia to count the number of times it successfully finds the search term within the tags.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

just put it in display at the top order and algolia will make more pound on the attribute